# upload Web Application Log file into S3

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have a requirement, we have one web Application.
from that application, we are downloading the Logs by clicking the Download Button ( manually).

After download using AWS CLI uploading the Logs into S3 then processing the data.

can we do automate this?

please help me to automate this If we can.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: What are you trying to automate? The upload of the file or the entire process, i.e. skip saving the file locally, but rather push it to S3, say, using "Upload to S3" button.

Comment: Entire process,

i.e, when a log created in an application, automatically  it should upload into S3

Comment: Well, then you will have to provide a bit more information on What language is the application written in, how are the logs created, etc. But as a guideline you can do this : Say you have a function that creates the logs in a certain file, in that function initialize AWS SDK client to communicate with S3 and directly upload the file from there in a specified bucket.

Comment: Can you simply modify the application to send the log files directly to Amazon S3? Or can you modify it to use CloudWatch Logs instead of a log file, so that CloudWatch Logs receives a continuous stream of logs (instead of waiting for you to press a button)? And what do you mean by "processing the data" after it is in S3?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a lambda function and assume a role of ec2-lambda and collect the logs and move them into a S3 bucket even with the time stamp as well you can even schedule it using cloud watch if you want the log backup at a specific time .
You can also use Ansible or Jenkins to do the task in Jenkins you can create a job and it has S3 plugin even available and simply run your Jenkins job which going to copy the logs to your s3 buckets